# Convert a String Value to ASCII

Tags: java, type-conversion

I want to take the value of a ASCII value(Saved as a string) and convert it to the character to reveal a message. I tried this and it keeps throwing an index out of bound at the declaration of the int b.It also shows that str and b do not have a value

String value = "104 101 108 108 111";

```
    char[] ch = new char[value.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        ch[i] = value.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(ch.length);
    String ans = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i+2 < ch.length) {
       
        
        int b= ch[i]+ch[i++]+ch[i+2];
        String str = new Character((char) b).toString();
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(b);
    ans = ans+str;
    i=i+3;
    }
```

Comment: Change `ch[i++]` to `ch[i+1]`

Answer (score 2):

Using string split function

```
    String value = "104 101 108 108 111";

    String[] arrOfStr = value.split(" "); 
    
    String ans = "";

    for(String str : arrOfStr) {
         String str1 = Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(str));
         ans += str1;
    }
    
    System.out.println(ans); // output: hello
```

Answer (score 0):

We can switch the `Imperative` code to `Declarative` code using Java 8 `Streams`.

**Key points to observe:**

1. Declarative style is more readable and easy to write.
2. String Joiner is faster than simple String Concatenation.
3. No need to write an iterator.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "104 101 108 108 111";

        Arrays.stream(value.split(" ")) // Starting a stream of String[]
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // mapping String to int
            .mapToObj(Character::toChars) // finding ASCII char from int
            .forEach(System.out::print); // printing each character
    }

}
```

If you wish to store the result and then print it, this is how is done.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "104 101 108 108 111";

        String result = Arrays.stream(value.split(" ")) // Starting a stream of String[]
                            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // mapping String to int
                            .mapToObj(Character::toChars) // finding ASCII char from int
                            .map(String::new) // convert char to String
                            .collect(Collectors.joining()); // combining individual result using String Joiner

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Comments to code:

There is a built-in method for for getting a `char[]` with the characters of a string, so the following two blocks of code are the same:

```java
// Code from question
char[] ch = new char[value.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
    ch[i] = value.charAt(i);
}

// Using built-in method
char[] ch = value.toCharArray();
```

It is better to use a `for` loop when increment a value while looping. The following two ways of writing the loop behave the same, but the `for` loop keeps the loop logic together:

```java
// Code from question
int i = 0;
while (i+2 < ch.length) {
    // some code here
    i=i+3;
}

// Using for loop
for (int i = 0; i + 2 < ch.length; i=i+3) {
    // some code here
}
```

The following line of code is entirely wrong:

```java
int b= ch[i]+ch[i++]+ch[i+2];
```

1. `i++` increments the value is `i`, but it is the value before the increment that is used in the expression, which means that if `i = 0` before the line, the result is the same as this code:

   ```java
   int b = ch[0] + ch[0] + ch[2];
   i = i + 1;
   ```

   You need to replace `i++` with `i + 1`, and realize that those are *not the same*.
2. Since you no longer increment the value of `i` by 1 in that statement, the loop much be changed from `i=i+3` to `i = i + 4`, to correctly skip the spaces in the input.
3. The value of `ch[i]` is a `char` value, which is widened to an `int` value by the use of the `+` operator. The `int` value of a `char` is the Unicode Code Point value, which for your text is also the same as the ASCII code for the character.

   This means that if `i = 0`, the expression would (after fixing issue #1) evaluate as:

   ```java
   int b = ch[0] + ch[1] + ch[2];

   int b = `1` + `0` + `4`;

   int b = 49 + 48 + 52;

   int b = 149;
   ```

   That matches the output from running the code is in question, where the second printed number is `149` (after fixing issue #1).

What you really wanted was to get the substring `"104"` and convert that to a number, then cast that ASCII code value to a `char`, like this:

```java
String numberStr = value.substring(i, i + 3); // E.g. "104"
int number = Integer.parseInt(numberStr);     // E.g. 104
String str = String.valueOf((char) number);   // E.g. "h"
```

With that, you no longer need the `char[]`, so the final code would be:

```java
String value = "104 101 108 108 111";

String ans = "";
for (int i = 0; i + 2 < value.length(); i += 4) {
    String numberStr = value.substring(i, i + 3);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberStr);
    String str = String.valueOf((char) number);
    ans = ans + str;
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

*Output*

```
hello
```